# iOS Bluetooth Device CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate don't get data

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

Bluetooth successfully connected.

**Call** - `(void)setNotifyValue:(BOOL)enabled forCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic;`

There is no callback -> `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:`

**properties**

|Read|Write|Indicate

Comment: Hello!Anyone??？

Comment: Who is use indicate?